# Does cryptocurrency ETF use block-chain technology?

Tags: blockchain, currencies, bitcoin-etf

As you know, one of these days trends is `cryptocurrency ETFs` that the CES doesn't approve it yet. But there are some questions about them and their functioning. Is it necessary to build them over block-chain technology? If yes, would someone explain it? and in case the answer is no, why?

**Question:** In other words, the main question is about how do they implemented and function.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it necessary to build [Exchange Traded Funds] over block-chain technology?**

No.

> **in case the answer is no, why?**

Imagine an ETF based on stocks in gold mining companies. Those companies own open-cast mines and rock-crushing machines.

An exchange can buy and sell shares, or funds based on those shares without directly themselves operating any open-cast mines or rock-crushers.

Rock-crushing machines are not suited to keeping track of sales and purchases of stocks and shares, or of funds based on them.